# Memory issues on drools while creating knowledge base

Tags: java, performance, drools

I am using drools5.5.0 in my application. I have a decision table which has 30,000 rules in it. A knowledge base need to be created with 10 such decision tables.

I have serialised those decision tables out and loading those packages into the knowledge base. However I cannot create knowledge base due to memory problems. 
Am having 16 gb as Java heap and 4 gb as permGen so far.

These are my questions.

Is it really requires these much memory or not??

If so., Is there anyother best practice to reduce the memory usage??

Comment: Duplicate to your [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18122013/out-of-memory-error-in-drools)?

Comment: Either way I didn't get any answer.

Comment: You should post updates to your original question on your progress, rather than start a new one. You even have an ongoing bounty there. I added a comment there also, have you consider what I suggest in that?

Comment: Just to be clear, my other ques is more about the implementation and this one is about the general memory management while using drools

Comment: It is possible for Drools to need that much memory to load a knowledge base. It all depends on the rules you have written. However, there is no single 'best practise' to reduce memory usage, so the second part of your question is meaningless unless you provide your rules as examples, which we could analyze and provide an actual answer to. In the absence of that, I would recommend this question being shut down as a duplicate.

Comment: @Steve : Thanks for your comment :) Now I can make sure that drools consumes memory based on the number of rules.